# HP laptop not charging over 86%, dies at 50% without warning

Tags: windows-10, laptop, battery, power

I'm running Windows 10 on an HP laptop. I always have to keep it charging because it doesn't charge past 86%, and it turns off itself at around 50% without any warning. Is this a problem with the battery or power settings?

Comment: Almost certainly the battery. Sounds like it's lost a cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you need to run the Battery Test and Calibration.

Check out - https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c00821536

Should correct the issue, or at least tell you if your battery is toast.

Comment: Nothing says Windows 10 on there. Is it still good to use?

Comment: It certainly wont' break anything. Try it.